# MySQL + NoSQL - Multilanguage support

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual, nosql

I have the following issue (I am trying to give the full context, if you are in a hurry, skip to the last paragraph):

We need to create a multilanguage support for a project. Our current database is MySQL.
Since the structure would need to change pretty much to allow it in the current DB, we got to the conclusion that the "classic" approach is not optimal.

By classic I mean adding lang tables, linking them with FKs, etc.

So we thought "let's save langs on file on disk". We analyzed that and is easier to implement, and looks ok as a solution. But then we got into the issue "what about concurrent access - we would need to implement something for this".

So we said... why not use a no sql db for this? It deals with concurrent access/lock, is outside our main db, is fast, scalable.

At first glance this looks like a good solution and we are willing to give it a try. But since we lack the experience with no sql... can any1 tell us if this is a good/bad idea and why (I explained how we got here and why we thought is a good idea)?

Comment: Check gettext function : [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php) [tuto](http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/07/php-internationalization-with-gettext-tutorial/). It s not an answer so i post as comment, but i think that can help you.

Comment: Ty. Looks interesting, but at first glance (correct me if I'm wrong pls, I only scanned it for like 1 min) it can be only used for static text (example: I can translate page title with it, but I can't translate the name of a book entered by user in the DB)?

Comment: You can create multiple domain, `bindtextdomain('static', DIR_LOCALE);
bindtextdomain('dynamic', DIR_LOCALE);` i set default domain `textdomain('static');` show static trad `echo _("msgid");` show dynamic trad `echo dgettext('dynamic', "msgid");`. You just have to store dynamic msgid in you database.

Comment: It s not perfect and that make many problem with msgid and size of dynamic domain if you have too many trad.